# How to add a push notification to a website?

Tags: javascript, php, html, push-notification

I am trying to add a push notification to my website. When the user logs in they will be presented with a notification reminding them to add their results. I found code off chrome pop ups but it dosen't seem to be working.

```
<script>
Notification.requestPermission(function(status) {
    console.log('Notification permission status:', status);
});

function displayNotification() {
 if(Notification.permission=="granted"){
                    jQuery('#notification-head').hide();
                    notify=new Notification("New Blog Available",{
                    body:"Demo paragraph",
                    icon:'bg-Img.png',
                    tag:'12222'
                    });
                    notify.onclick=function(){
                    notify.close();
    }  
}
</script>
```

Comment: Well, at least you lack an ending } in your displayNotification function

Comment: @Rantanen, I think it's more like a desktop notification, not a popup alert like that.

Comment: @entiendoNull thanks I have added an extra } but it only asks me if I allow the notification, it dosen't actually display!

Comment: You are requesting permission before you check if it has already been granted.

Comment: Just replace your code with the example found on mdn... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Notifications_API/Using_the_Notifications_API

Comment: @baao yes I am, then I want to post "Demo Paragraph" if the user agrees to the post notification

Comment: Once having the permission, doing this works fine for me in Chrome: `new Notification("New Blog Available", {body:"Demo paragraph"});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a curly brace at the end of your function. You can look at [this example](https://tricksfortheweb.com/notifications.html). Also, you are never calling the `displayNotification`, you need to use this:

```
Notification.requestPermission(function(status) {
  console.log('Notification permission status:', status);
  displayNotification();
});

function displayNotification() {
    if(Notification.permission == "granted"){
    $('#notification-head').hide();
    let notify = new Notification("New Blog Available", {
        body:"Demo paragraph",
        icon:'bg-Img.png',
        tag:'12222'
    });
    notify.onclick = function(){
     notify.close();
    }  
    }
}
```

Comment: You are requesting permission before you check if it has already been granted.

Comment: So what? If it's already been granted it won't make a difference.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I made a minor edit to be able to remove it

Comment: Ok, no problem.